# How can I eliminate all continuous or page breaks in a Word document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word application which generates a document containing a boatload of Word tables and nothing else.  In the end, I want a single table containing hundreds of rows which could potentially spread over a couple hundred pages.  However, it is far easier to generate this document a table at a time with some sort of a break, be it a page break or continuous section break, between tables.

While the tables are numerous, they all contain multiple rows with two columns taking up 20% and 80% of the width.  Row 1 always has both cells merged.  I've found that having merged cells impacts performance such that some operations, here the width setting, sporadically fail.  Adding a DoEvents or delay between iterations helps somewhat, but the best thing I've found for this is to do the cell merge for all the tables after they have been initially built.

Now that the document containing all the tables has been generated, what's a "better" way to remove the section breaks such that all the tables become fused together as one?

This has worked for me, first to attempt removing the breaks with something like this:

```
With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
   .ClearAllFuzzyOptions
   .ClearFormatting
   .Text = "^m" ' for page breaks
   ' .Text = "^b" ' when searching for continuous section breaks
   .Replacement.Text = ""
   .Execute Replace:=WdReplace.wdReplaceAll
End With
```

Interestingly, when a continuous section break is used, this code fragment only removes  **the very last occurrence**, as does the replace facility in the Word ribbon.  When a page break is used, all page breaks are removed, however this leaves two stray paragraphs between tables.  These can be cleaned up with something like the following:

```
For i = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count To 1 Step -1
    If Not ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

This works but is understandably rather slow. (There are some 4000 paragraphs in total, 50 of which are candidates for removal)

In the end, using page breaks plus cleanup works but is very slow.  Ideally, the first code fragment should work with continuous section breaks, which should require no downstream cleanup.  Suggestions?

This is using MS Office 2016.

This program replicates the problem on my system.

```
Public Sub test()

    Dim Word As Word.Application: Set Word = New Word.Application
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    
    Word.Visible = True
    Word.Activate
    Word.ScreenUpdating = True
    Word.Documents.Add
    
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim t As Integer: t = 0
    Dim myrange As Word.Range: Set myrange = ActiveDocument.Content
    myrange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    
    For j = 0 To 25
           
        ' depending on a blank row, add either a single row or rows for all the countries' answers
        t = t + 1
        ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=myrange, NumRows:=25 + 2, NumColumns:=2
        
        With ActiveDocument.Tables(t)
            .rows(1).Cells(1).Range.Text = "Header " & j
            .Borders.Enable = True
            .Columns(1).PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
            .Columns(1).PreferredWidth = 20
            .Columns(2).PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
            .Columns(2).PreferredWidth = 80
        End With

        For i = 0 To 25
            With ActiveDocument.Tables(t).rows(i + 2)
                .Cells(1).Range.Text = "Text " & i & " " & j
                .Cells(2).Range.Text = "More Text " & i & " " & j
            End With
            DoEvents
        Next i

        Set myrange = ActiveDocument.Content
        myrange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        myrange.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakContinuous
        
    Next j
   
    ' fix up row 1 for all tables
    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
        With ActiveDocument.Tables(i)
           .rows(1).Cells.Merge
           .rows(1).Cells(1).Range.Style = "Heading 3"
           .rows(1).Cells(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGray25
        End With
        DoEvents
    Next i
    
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearAllFuzzyOptions
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "^b"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Execute Replace:=WdReplace.wdReplaceAll
    End With
    
    For i = Word.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Not Word.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
            Word.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Delete
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: ^m only finds Page Breaks. To find Section Breaks, use ^b. You can find double paragraph marks with ^p^p and replace them with a single ^p.

Comment: @JohnKorchok Nope, .Text = "^b" only gets the very last continuous section break.  I will clarify accordingly.

Comment: Your code should replace all section breaks with "^b". Do you have stale "Find" parameters that you must first clear with `.ClearAllFuzzyOptions` and `.ClearFormatting`?

Comment: @GSerg It still only eliminates the last continuous section break

Comment: It removes all section breaks for me. Are you sure the breaks you have are indeed `^b`s?

Comment: To find Section Breaks, use ^b _in a manual find and replace_. Using find and replace in VBA is more complex that doing a manual search. Please see this page: https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/vba_find_and_replace.html

Comment: Try the code fragment.  Note that this was originally written to run from Excel.